# Trying to correct MySQL query to return desired result w/ joined table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a vehicle search resource.  Based on our current query, MySQL is returning the correct results.  However, the results are not what I'm looking for.  I know there's a mistake in the query, but not sure how to rectify it.

Here are the tables:

**vehicles table**

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | active |    label     |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | test vehicle | 2016-03-14 15:34:00 | 2016-03-14 15:34:00 |
+----+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**vehicles_metas table**

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | active | vehicle_id |  meta_key  |    meta_value    |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 |          1 | type       | Performance Boat | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  2 |      1 |          1 | make       | Deep Impact      | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  3 |      1 |          1 | model      | Cuddy Cabin      | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  4 |      1 |          1 | year       | 2014             | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  5 |      1 |          1 | length     | 39               | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  6 |      1 |          1 | propulsion | (4) Mercury 350  | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  7 |      1 |          1 | hull       | fiberglass       | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
|  8 |      1 |          1 | price      | 399000           | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 | 2016-03-14 15:36:00 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**current mysql query**

```
select `vehicles`.`id` from `vehicles` inner join `vehicle_metas` on `vehicle_metas`.`vehicle_id` = `vehicles`.`id` where (`vehicle_metas`.`meta_key` = 'type' and `vehicle_metas`.`meta_value` LIKE '%perf%') and (`vehicle_metas`.`meta_key` = 'model' and `vehicle_metas`.`meta_value` LIKE '%cuddy%')
```

As of right now, the query results in zero rows returned.  If I only use one of the two `meta_key & meta_value` query filters, the record `vehicle_id: 1` is returned.

I'm simply trying to return the vehicle ID that matches all `meta` query filters.

Comment: Note: We're using Laravel 5.2 on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@robestrong explained why you are not getting any results back from your current query.

He suggested a solution with join, let me suggest another solution using [exists subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select `vehicles`.`id`
from `vehicles`
inner join `vehicle_metas` vm1 on vm1.`vehicle_id` = `vehicles`.`id`
where vm1.`meta_key` = 'type' and vm1.`meta_value` LIKE '%perf%' and EXISTS (select 1 FROM `vehicle_metas` vm2 WHERE vm2.`meta_key` = 'model' and vm2.`meta_value` LIKE '%cuddy%' and vm2.vehicle_id=vm1.vehicle_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `EXISTS` evaluation.  This solution worked well.  We're using Laravel, which offers the `EXISTS` evaluator natively.

Answer (score 0):

It works when only one of them is enabled, because it's applying it to each row. So the key isn't both type and model on each row, same for the perf and cuddy bit.

What you want to do isn't OR, though, because you do need to select the vehicle_id where both of those are true.

Off the cuff what I'd do is perform select * with just one of them first, then perform an inner join of that with vehicle_metas and then select vehicles.id from that with the second requirement.

That should give you the subset of vehicles.id where both criteria are met.

Something like this (untested):

```
select vehicles.id from

(select *

from vehicles inner join vehicle_metas

on vehicle_metas.vehicle_id = vehicles.id

where (vehicle_metas.meta_key = 'type' and vehicle_metas.meta_value LIKE '%perf%'))

as subset inner join vehicle_metas

on subset.vehicle_id = vehicle_metas.vehicle_id

where

(vehicle_metas.meta_key = 'model' and vehicle_metas.meta_value LIKE '%cuddy%')
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Could you provide a rough, or untested, example?  Thank you very much.

Comment: You explained just fine why the OP's current query returns no records. But I would beef up the proposed solution part because it is a bit hard to follow. Some code example would not hurt either.

Comment: @Shadow I'll update it. New to SO so still getting a feel for how things work here.

Comment: @user2977468 added some code. Might be a bug or two, but that's the logic.

Comment: Thank you both, Robe & Shadow.  I'm reviewing & testing suggestions right now.

Comment: Thank you again, Robestrong.  Your (original) explanation was pretty conceptual, which personally, I appreciate.  It helped to clarify my conundrum.  I selected Shadow's answer for 2 reasons: 1. Ease of implementation w/ Laravel.  & 2. For future readers to see the ease of leveraging  `EXISTS` for sub-queries.

Comment: The logic is fine, but it is overcomplicated. There is no need for subselects, just do a self join on vehicle_metas and you can apply the different criteria to the 2 version of the same table.

Comment: Yep, that works too. This was just the most obvious way that popped into my head.